# How to cache form inputs properly in node.js?

Tags: node.js, forms, caching, express, ejs

I am new to node.js and what I want to do is to pass inputted form data after form processing back to the input fields if there is something erroneous in the data passed in the form (example : username is already in use). I am trying to do it with the help of EJS but the form does not seem to retrieve the value.

Below is my app.js code snippet:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/',function(req,res){
  var username = req.body.username;
  res.render('registration', {title: 'Registration',
                            username: username});
});
```

Below is my registration.ejs code snippet:

```
<form class="form"  action="/" method="post" name="regForm">

              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" value="<% username %>" name="username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" onblur="validateUsername(this.value)" required>
              </div>
</form>
```

Upon posting I am expecting the field of username to be filled with the value I inputted but it does not seem to happen. What could be causing it?

Am I doing this cache thing properly or is there any way to cache form inputs better?

Comment: Are you sure that `req.body.username` is a string? Are you using the appropriate body parsing middleware (e.g. `body-parser`'s `urlencoded()` middleware)?

Comment: I have this in my code : app.use(bodyParser.json()); This is what you are referring to right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })` form parsing middleware since the HTML form is submitting an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` form, not `application/json`-formatted form data.

Comment: Not unless you have other form submissions that send `application/json`-formatted requests.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong. I forgot to put "=" after <% in my EJS code. It worked after that.